# How to add record in datatable flet python?

Tags: python, flet

I want the user to enter the values and press the plus button to display all the values in the `TextField` in the data table and in my code to access these records through a list.
In the picture below, the data table is created again from the beginning, if I want it to be added as a record in the data table every time the value is entered in the TextField and the add option is pressed by the user.
The point is that I want these records to be in the list in the source

```
def main(page: ft.Page):
    def add_clicked(e):
        page.add(
            ft.DataTable(
                columns=[
                    ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("First name")),
                    ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Last name")),
                    ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Age")),
                ],
                rows=[
                    ft.DataRow(
                        cells=[
                            ft.DataCell(ft.Text(new_task.value)),
                            ft.DataCell(ft.Text(new_task1.value)),
                            ft.DataCell(ft.Text(new_task2.value)),
                        ],
                    ),
                ]

            )



        )
        # page.add(ft.DataCell(ft.Text(new_task.value)))
        # page.add(ft.DataCell(ft.Text(new_task1.value)))
        # page.add(ft.DataCell(ft.Text(new_task2.value)))
        # page.add(ft.Checkbox(label=new_task.value))
        # page.add(ft.Checkbox(label=new_task1.value))
        # page.add(ft.Checkbox(label=new_task2.value))
        new_task.value = ""
        new_task1.value = ""
        new_task2.value = ""
        page.update()

    new_task = ft.TextField(hint_text="Whats needs to be done?")
    new_task1 = ft.TextField(hint_text="Whats needs to be done?")
    new_task2 = ft.TextField(hint_text="Whats needs to be done?")

    page.add(new_task,new_task1,new_task2, ft.FloatingActionButton(icon=ft.icons.ADD, on_click=add_clicked),

             )

ft.app(target=main)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add the new record entered by the user to the existing data table in the list, you can modify the add_clicked function to update the rows list with the new record before creating the DataTable

```
def add_clicked(e):
    # Get the existing rows
    existing_rows = page.get_table_data("my_table") or []
    
    # Create a new row with the values entered by the user
    new_row = ft.DataRow(
        cells=[
            ft.DataCell(ft.Text(new_task.value)),
            ft.DataCell(ft.Text(new_task1.value)),
            ft.DataCell(ft.Text(new_task2.value)),
        ],
    )
    
    # Add the new row to the existing rows
    rows = existing_rows + [new_row]
    
    # Create the data table with the updated rows
    table = ft.DataTable(
        columns=[
            ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("First name")),
            ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Last name")),
            ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Age")),
        ],
        rows=rows,
        name="my_table"
    )
    
    # Replace the existing data table with the new one
    page.replace(table)
    
    # Clear the text fields
    new_task.value = ""
    new_task1.value = ""
    new_task2.value = ""
```

Comment: You could also just use a Ref to the existing DataTable and update the rows property; without having to replace the existing table.