# how to dynamically add rows in flet python datatable?

Tags: python, flet

I found a piece of code on the internet for kivymd, where I can add or remove text field values to the data table by pressing the Add button (as shown below).
But is this possible for Flet Python? How?
Even I have appended all the rows of the data table in one list, how can I do this in flet?
The information in the link below is not useful for me
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75640444/how-to-add-record-in-datatable-flet-python)
I have written the following pieces of code in Flat Python

```
import flet as ft
from flet import *



class App(UserControl):
    first_name = ft.TextField(label="First name",text_align=ft.TextAlign.RIGHT, width=185,height=50)
    last_name = ft.TextField(label="Last name",text_align=ft.TextAlign.RIGHT, width=185,height=50)
    Age = ft.TextField(label="Age",text_align=ft.TextAlign.RIGHT, width=185,height=50)

    data_table = ft.DataTable(
            columns=[
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("First name")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Last name")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("Age")),
                ft.DataColumn(ft.Text("No.")),
            ],

            rows=[
                ft.DataRow([ft.DataCell(ft.Text("1")), ft.DataCell(ft.Text(f"{First_name}")), ft.DataCell(ft.Text(f"{Last_name}"))
                               , ft.DataCell(ft.Text(f"{Age}"))


                            ],),
                


            ],
        )

    def add_btn(e):
        pass


    def build(self):
        return Column(
            controls=[
                Container(
                    width=Container.width.fget,
                    # width=1200,
                    height=300,

                    
                    # bgcolor=colors.AMBER_300,
                    bgcolor="#ffffe0",
                    border_radius=border_radius.all(5),

                    content=Column(
                        controls=[
                            Row(
                                # alignment="spaceAround",
                                spacing=2,
                                controls=[
                                    # self.txt_number
                                    Container(
                                        margin=margin.only(top=10,right=10),
                                        width=180,
                                        height=50,
                                        bgcolor="#ffffe0",
                                        content=Column(controls=[self.first_name])

                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                        margin=margin.only(top=10, right=5),
                                        width=185,
                                        height=50,
                                        bgcolor="#ffffe0",
                                        content=Column(controls=[self.last_name])

                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                        margin=margin.only(top=10, right=5),
                                        width=185,
                                        height=50,
                                        bgcolor="#ffffe0",
                                        content=Column(controls=[self.Age])

                                    ),
      
                            ElevatedButton(
                                text="Elevated button",
                                bgcolor="Green",
                                width=200,
                                height=40,
                                on_click= self.add_btn,
                            ),
                        ],
                    ),


                ),
                Container(
                    width=Container.width.fget,
                    # width=1200,
                    height=300,


                    # bgcolor=colors.AMBER_300,
                    bgcolor="#ffffe0",
                    border_radius=border_radius.all(5),
                    content=Column(
                        controls=[
                                self.data_table
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
            ]
        )







def main(page: Page):

    
    page.title = "flet tutorial"

    page.rtl =True
    
    page.window_width =1200
    page.window_height=700

    
    page.window_resizable=False


    page.bgcolor ="#e249fc"

    
    page.update()





    
    app = App()
    page.add(app)





if __name__ =="__main__":
    flet.app(target=main)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `DataTable`, the member rows are of type `list[Row]`,
so inserting a `Row` into the list at a desired location is the way to update it. This gets reflected dynamically.

For example, you can add a behavior like adding a row to the table when the elevated button is pressed.

This can be achieved by implementing the `on_click` event routine with `add_btn()` as below:

```
def add_btn(self):
        self.data_table.rows.insert(len(self.data_table.rows), ft.DataRow([ft.DataCell(ft.Text("1")), ft.DataCell(ft.Text(f"First_name")), ft.DataCell(ft.Text(f"Last_name"))
                               , ft.DataCell(ft.Text(f"Age"))],)) 
        self.update()
```